# Generalization of Schur's lemma (Update)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

I am not a mathematician nor physicist. I just know the basics of the representation theory. In my research, I realized that there is an orthogonality relation between the unitary group matrix elements as follows:

$$I_1 = \int \mathrm{D}\mathbf{U} \; U_{i j}^{(\mathbf{r})} U_{k l }^{*(\mathbf{r}^{\prime})} = \frac{1}{ d_{ \mathbf{r} } } \delta_{\mathbf{r} \mathbf{r}^{\prime} }  \delta_{i k} \delta_{j l}
$$

where $\mathbf{U} \in \mathcal{U}(N)$, $\mathrm{D}\mathbf{U}$ is the standard Haar measure, $U_{ij}^{(\mathbf{r})}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th element of the representation matrix of $\mathbf{U}$, and $d_{ \mathbf{r} }$ is the dimension of the irreducible representation $\mathbf{r}$.

Now, I need to know the answer for this integral:

$$I_2 = \int \mathrm{D} \mathbf{U} \; U_{i_1 j_1}^{(\mathbf{r})} U_{ k_1 l_1 }^{ * ( \mathbf{r} ) } U_{ i_2 j_2 }^{(\mathbf{r}^{\prime})} U_{ k_2 l_2 }^{* ( \mathbf{r}^{ \prime \prime } ) }
$$

I appreciate any help.

p.s. Here is my conjecture for the answer:

$$
I_2 = \delta_{ \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \mathbf{r}^{\prime \prime} } \times \left\{
 \eqalign{
\frac{1}{ d_{ \mathbf{r} } d_{ \mathbf{r}^{ \prime } } -1 } \delta_{ i_1 k_1 } \delta_{ j_1 l_1 } \delta_{ i_2 k_2 } \delta_{ j_2 l_2 } ( 1- \delta_{ \mathbf{r} \mathbf{r}^{\prime} } ) \\
 + \delta_{ \mathbf{r} \mathbf{r}^{\prime} } \left[
     \eqalign{
      \frac{ 1 }{ d_{ \mathbf{r} }^2 -1 }
 ( \delta_{ i_1 k_1 } \delta_{ j_1 l_1 } \delta_{ i_2 k_2 } \delta_{ j_2 l_2 }
 + \delta_{ i_1 k_2 } \delta_{ j_1 l_2 } \delta_{ i_2 k_1 } \delta_{ j_2 l_1 } ) \\
 - \frac{ 1 }{ d_{ \mathbf{r} } ( d_{ \mathbf{r} }^2 -1 ) } ( \delta_{ i_1 k_1 } \delta_{ j_1 l_2 } \delta_{ i_2 k_2 } \delta_{ j_2 l_1 } + \delta_{ i_1 k_2 } \delta_{ j_1 l_1 }  \delta_{ i_2 k_1 } \delta_{ j_2 l_2 } )  }
    \right] 
} \right\} $$

**UPDATE:**

I have been advised that it might be helpful if I can find the tensor product of two irreducible representations, $ \mathbf{s} = \mathbf{r} \otimes \mathbf{r}^{\prime}$, which most likely leads to a reducible representation, and then I need to decompose $\mathbf{s}$ into its irreducible components (by using the Clebsch–Gordan coefficients, according to wikipedia), to be able to use the Schur's lemma to get the answer!!!

However, it is hard for me to do this, and needs awful background.

Comment: Why do call this a generalisation of the Schur's Lemma?  It seems to me like a generalisation of the Peter-Weyl theorem instead.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but this seems to me like the sort of calculation that lattice gauge theorists might know how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 

p.s. The mathematicians I have talked to so far call I_1 the Schur's lemma. 

Comment: Do you really want two ${\bf r}$'s, one ${\bf r'}$ and one ${\bf r''}$ in your expression? Or is there a typo?

Comment: Yes. In my problem, I have 3 distinct representations. There is no typo error. However, my conjecture for the answer is that $I_2=0$ if $\mathbf{r}^{\prime} \neq \mathbf{r}^{\prime \prime}$. 

Comment: I don't think your conjecture can be right. Look at $SU(2)$. Suppose ${\bf r}=3$, ${\bf r}'=5$ and ${\bf r''=7}$. Then the tensor products decompose into irreducible representations as: $R_3\otimes R_5=R_3\oplus R_5 \oplus R_7$ and $R_3\otimes R_7=R_5\oplus R_7\oplus R_9$, where $R_n$ is the irreducible representation of dimension $n$. When you sum over your indices $i_{1,2},\, j_{1,2},\, k_{1,2},\, l_{1,2}$, you should get $12=5+7$, not $0$, since these overlap in $R_5$ and $R_7$. How this sum of $12$ is distributed over $i_{1,2},\,j_{1,2},\,k_{1,2},\,l_{1,2}$ is a mystery to me. 


Comment: If you want a simpler example to think about, you could take ${\bf r}=2$, ${\bf r}' = 2$ and ${\bf r}'' = 4$. Then the tensor products decompose as $R_2 \otimes R_2=R_1\oplus R_3$ and $R_2\otimes R_4=R_3\oplus R_5$.

Comment: I've looked at the previous example, and unless I did something wrong (quite possible) it looks to me like the terms add up (and cancel) in rather unexpected ways. I'll group them according to $(l_1,l_2)$. For $l_1=2$, $l_2=2$, there are six non-zero terms, each contributing an $I_2=1/12$. The same holds for $(l_1,l_2) \in \{(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)\}$ If you take $l_1=1$, $l_2=1$, you get one term contributing $1/4$, and the same holds for $(l_1,l_2) \in \{(1,1),(1,4),(4,1),(4,4)\}$. For the remaining pairs $(l_1, l_2)$, you get various terms of $\pm \sqrt{3}/12$, which all end up canceling.

Comment: This is clearly basis-dependent (I used the $z$-momentum basis, which is the standard basis for $SU(2)\,$), and it isn't ending up looking very nice. I suppose it might be nicer in a different basis. I suspect you could work out everything for the group $U(2)$, but it won't be easy. And $U(N)$ for larger $N$ are going to be a lot worse.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, It looks much more complicated than I first thought. If it is hopeless for you mathematicians, maybe I should give up. :( 

Comment: I guess it depends on how much you need to solve the problem, and whether $U(2)$ will help you, or whether you need $U(N)$. For $U(2)$, I suspect that if you worked out a bunch of small examples, and looked at them, you could figure out the pattern. And $U(2)$ has enough nice structure that it should be possible to prove your answer. In general, however, it's a lot hairier doing things explicitly in $U(N)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I do not know the answer to your problem, but here's a counterexample to your conjecture that the result is zero if $r'\ne r''$.
take $r=(2,1)$ (i.e., the Young diagram with two boxes one the first row and one on the second). then in the decomposition into irreducible representations of $r=(2,1)$ with its dual $r^\star=(...,-1,-2)$ one finds $(2,...,-1,-1)$ and $(1,1,...,-2)$. now these occur naturally as the tensor product of $r'=(2)$ and the dual of $r''=(1,1)$, or vice versa. ergo, $r\otimes r^\star\otimes r'\otimes r''^\star$ contains the trivial representation so that the integral of some of its matrix elements will be non-zero.